# преобразовать массив объектов с подмассивом объектов в массив объектов

Tags: javascript

Преобразовать такой массив объектов:

```
let value = [
  {

    "category": "new"
    "list": [
      {
        "item": 552
      },
      {
        "item": 564
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "category": "old"
    "list": [
      {
        "item": 435
      },
      {
        "item": 434
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

в

```
[
  {
    "item": 552
  },
  {
    "item": 564
  },
  {
    "item": 435
  },
  {
    "item": 434
  }
]
```

Пробовал так, но получаются все равно два отдельных массива

```
for(let item of t){
  console.log(item.list.filter((item) => item.hasOwnProperty('item')));
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

можно воспользоваться методом [`flatMap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap)

```js
let value = [{

    "category": "new",
    "list": [{
        "item": 552
      },
      {
        "item": 564
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "category": "old",
    "list": [{
        "item": 435
      },
      {
        "item": 434
      }
    ]
  }
];

console.log(value.flatMap(v => v.list));
```

Либо связкой методов [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) и [`concat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat)

```js
let value = [{

    "category": "new",
    "list": [{
        "item": 552
      },
      {
        "item": 564
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "category": "old",
    "list": [{
        "item": 435
      },
      {
        "item": 434
      }
    ]
  }
];

console.log(value.reduce((acc, cur) => acc.concat(cur.list), []));
```

Comment: Но если в браузере код надо запускать, то осторожнее. В ослах не работает.

Comment: @AlexSazonov, добавил альтернативный метод.

Comment: Альтернативный метод в IE все равно не сработает. Стрелочная функция же.

Comment: @Yaant, это уже другая проблема, для которой есть вопросы дубликаты :-)